# how to investigate what a process is doing?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I know this can be checked from /proc/PID directory,

but don't know how to,

can any one show me the way?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com, I think (asking to monitor a process via the filesystem). Additionally, you need to tell us what especifically you want to monitor about a process to help you better

Comment: I am looking for monitoring a php programme

Comment: Monitor what about it... its memory consumption, its network activity, who has called it, ... ?

Comment: I'm monitoring a xmpp robot,so should be classified as network activity.

Comment: I'm monitoring a xmpp robot,it easily get offline while the process is still alive,I'm investigating the reason.

Comment: @omg I know this was quite a few years ago, but could you please mark the answer as answer?

Answer (score 25):

Usually strace is the answer to this question. The simplest method is to run a command using strace directly, for example:

```
wichert@fog:~$ strace ls
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9fa8000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7f0a000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

This does not work for already running processes such as PHP. Luckily you can also attach strace to an existing process using the *-p* parameter. For example:

```
wichert@fog:~$ strace -p 3761
Process 3761 attached - interrupt to quit
select(16, [5 7 8], NULL, [5 7 8], {0, 580000}) = 0 (Timeout)
alarm(0)                                = 62
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_DFL}, {0x809a270, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
```

For daemons which spawn other processes you may need to use the *-f* parameter as well.

Besides the always useful strace you may also want to look at *ltrace*. ltrace is similar to strace, but it shows library calls instead of system calls. An example:

```
[one;~]-6> ltrace ls
__libc_start_main(0x804e5f0, 1, 0xbfdb7254, 0x8059a10, 0x8059a00 <unfinished ...>
setlocale(6, "")                                                                                 = "LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC="...
bindtextdomain("coreutils", "/usr/share/locale")                                                 = "/usr/share/locale"
textdomain("coreutils")                                                                          = "coreutils"
__cxa_atexit(0x8051860, 0, 0, 0xb7f65ff4, 0xbfdb71b8)                                            = 0
isatty(1)                                                                                        = 1
getenv("QUOTING_STYLE")                                                                          = NULL
```

Please note that you will also see a fair amount of internal libc calls as well, so the output could be more verbose than you expect.

Comment: It was also a huge help for me when I learned about `strace -f` which will follow the subprocesses of the one you are tracing. Finally, additional info can often be retreived when looking into the contents of `/proc/<process_id>` for the numbers on the left of `strace -f`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for monitoring the system calls being made by a process, look into using [strace](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FStrace&ei=dAUTSq78OZiwtAPXhbH2DQ&usg=AFQjCNFP2X7tTJp8k8MqQDTc-17BAfIbaA&sig2=d1x_fuKGEYS6s2fd_aF_lA).

Comment: I am looking for monitoring a php programme.
Will that help?

Comment: Well it will at least tell you what system calls the PHP interpreter are calling. Depending on what the PHP script is doing it may be useful or it may not. Otherwise you may want to look into PHP debugging.

Comment: I'm monitoring a xmpp robot,it easily get offline while the process is still alive,I'm investigating the reason.

Comment: For that I might consider modifying the PHP files to write to log files to try and figure out patterns that cause the offline problems.

Answer (score 7):

A great tool to use is ps and lsof. You can use ps to find the PID or process ID of that process or use ps -u {process-username} to get it's PID.  Then use lsof to see which files have been opened by that PID like so `lsof -p pid`.

Also you can use netstat to show all connections and corresponding ports.

Answer (score 2):

I rely on the `strace` command. But it only tells what system calls the process is making. It could be enough though...

It is possible to bind a running process to `strace` at runtime.

Obviously, `gdb` can also be used.

Comment: Can you make a demo on how to use strace to tell what a PHP programme is doing?

Answer (score 0):

what type of information are you looking for ?  The pseudo-directories under /proc/pid should be pretty much self explanatory.  It really depends what your looking for.  For general mem and cpu usage a tool like top is probably better since it updates the stats for a configured interval

Comment: I'm monitoring a xmpp robot,it easily get offline while the process is still alive,I'm investigating the reason.